# boost::signals2 thread-safe destruction

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-signals2

I have a class that contains a [boost::signals2::scoped_connection](https://beta.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/boost/signals2/scoped_connection.html) as a data member. This connection contains a slot which, when triggered, will print another data member in the class to stdout:

```
struct A {
   A(boost::signals2::signal<void()>& connection)
    : scoped_connection_{connection.connect([this]() {
          std::cout << foo_ << std::endl;
      })} {}

    std::string foo_{"foo"};
    boost::signals2::scoped_connection scoped_connection_;
};
```

This code can segfault in a multi-threaded scenario if a thread fires the signal (hence executing the lambda), but another thread destroys the object at the same time:

```
using Signal = boost::signals2::signal<void()>;

struct A {
    A(Signal& connection)
        : scoped_connection_{connection.connect([this]() {
              std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
              // foo is destroyed at this point...
              std::cout << foo_ << std::endl; // segfault
          })} {}

    std::string foo_{"Kaboom"};
    boost::signals2::scoped_connection scoped_connection_;
};

int main() {
    Signal sig;
    auto a = std::make_unique<A>(sig);

    std::thread t([&sig]() { sig(); });

    // give the thread some time to start and signal the slots
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));

    // destroy a as the callback is executing...
    a.reset();
   
    t.join();
    return 0;
}
```

This code segfaults because the destruction of `scoped_connection` is not synchronized with the execution of the slot's callback. In other words `scoped_connection` can be destroyed *even if the callback is currently running*.

This was surprising behavior for me, I would have expected `scoped_connection`'s destructor to block execution until the callback has finished.

Now I'm faced with the challenge of making above's code thread-safe by synchronizing destruction with callback execution and haven't been able to find a satisfactory solution. Maybe some of you can shed some light of a possible approach I can try out.

[Here godbolt link reproducing the segfault](https://godbolt.org/z/GxGq1fxdz)

Answer (score 0):

> This was surprising behavior for me, I would have expected scoped_connection's destructor to block execution until the callback has finished.

The `scoped_connection`'s release only synchronizes on *invocation*. This means that manipulating the signal doesn't create a data race. Whatever you share in the handler itself is your own responsibility.

So you could play fast and loose and "detect" that the slot was disconnected:

```
if (scoped_connection_.connected())
    std::cout << foo_ << std::endl;
```

However that's still intrinsically racy (though it will be very rare to hit, and probably never given the example timings).

---

Better, take shared ownership of the shared resource:

**[Live On Coliru](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd1df0de4542fa12)**

```
#include <boost/signals2.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <thread>

using Signal = boost::signals2::signal<void()>;

struct A {
    A(Signal& sig)
        : scoped_connection_{sig.connect([s = state_] {
            std::cout << "Executing callback" << std::endl;
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
            // foo is shared owned
            std::cout << s->foo_ << std::endl;
        })} {}

    ~A() { std::cout << "Destroying A" << std::endl; }

    struct State {
        std::string foo_;
        ~State() { std::cout << "Destroying shared state" << std::endl; }
    };
    std::shared_ptr<State>             state_ = std::make_shared<State>(State{"Naboo"});
    boost::signals2::scoped_connection scoped_connection_;
};

int main() {
    Signal sig;
    auto a = std::make_shared<A>(sig);  // register "a" as a slot
    std::thread t([&sig]() { sig(); });
    // give the thread some time to start and signal the slots
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    // destroy a as the callback is executing...
    a.reset();
    t.join();
}
```

Printing

```
Destroying shared state
Executing callback
Destroying A
Naboo
Destroying shared state
```

Of course the current example could be much simplified: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8faf77323a390921 but I'm assuming your code represents more interesting code

Comment: For completeness, a classic pattern is `std::enable_shared_from_this` but is is fundamentally incompatible with connection-from-constructor: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fd85cc456d55c55b

Answer (score 0):

First observation would be to pay a bit more overhead by switching to `shared_ptr` instead of `unique_ptr`:

```
struct A{
    A(Signal& sig):
        foo_{std::make_shared<std::string>("foo message")}
    {
        sig.connect([foo_]{
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
            // foo is not destroyed at this point...
            std::cout << *foo_ << std::endl; // no segfault
        });
    };
    std::shared_ptr<std::string> foo_;
};
```

But this forces the object to live as long as the slot references it. To gain better control you need to `track` slot-bound objects:

```
using slot=signal::slot_type;

struct A{
    A(Signal& sig):
         data_{std::make_shared<slot_data>()}
    {
         data_->scoped_connection_ = sig.connect(slot{[&foo_=data_->foo_]{
              std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));
              // foo is life extended at this point...
              std::cout << foo_ << std::endl; // no segfault
          }}.track_foreign(data_));
    };
    struct slot_data{
        std::string foo_{"Kaboom"};
        boost::signals2::scoped_connection scoped_connection_;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<slot_data> data_;
};
```

By `track`ing the `weak_ptr`, `slot` checks if the shared object is in its valid lifetime, before execution; if the answer is yes, then the `shared_ptr` is life extended for the duration of slot execution; but if the answer is no, the slot is dropped from execution.

**EDIT:**
Removed the `enable_shared_from_this`, because of impossiblity of using `shared_from_this` in constructor.
This solution costs more than   I would like to pay.

Comment: The examples invoke Undefined Behaviour because `shared_from_this` and `weak_from_this` must not be used from the constructor. (I had in fact mentioned this already [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77239184/boostsignals2-thread-safe-destruction#comment136168527_77239659)) Nice info with `track_foreign`. That can be very useful.

Comment: @sehe  The first one does, but the second should not. Because in the second sample the object is not accessed in initializer list, So the execution is sequenced after the base CRTP mixin is constructed. First example should've been fixed too, but the canon was supposed to be the second.

Comment: If I were using `boost::shared_ptr`, `track` method would be used: it has ashorter name.

Comment: You are using shared_ptr though. I get what you mean (regarding `track_foreign`), but weak_ptr cannot exist in isolation. Your answer code is broken.

Comment: @sehe No. It is not broken. When you `enable_shared_from_this`, the `weak_ptr` mus exist and you are supposed to instantiate only `shared_ptr`s to class. The base class subobject is already initialized when the body of constructor gets executed, so calling base methods is safe. The first snippet puts the call to base method in initializer list of constructor, which may actually run the method prior to base constructor, therefore you have a point about first snippet. Second snippet is just ok.

Comment: Have you tried? If you mean it is "just ok" as "it doesn't crash" - you're quite right! It also doesn't _work_. It cannot work: https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/828567e8f42d510c This kind of shows the power of live demos.

Comment: You still have my +1 for the `track_foreign` bit by the way. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: You made me search for it. It's a design problem in `enable_shared_from_this`. I have to fix it. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20220720-00/?p=106877